# Can you recover to a point in time using the LDF?

Tags: sql-server, recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get back some deleted records?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/995/how-do-i-get-back-some-deleted-records)

A coworker accidentally ran an update statement that needs to be reverted. The last backup is about 12 hours old.

Is there any way to rollback to a point in time just using LDF file?

Every example I was able to find mentions *.trn files to be used...

Comment: Are you using full recovery model or simple recovery model?

Comment: Step 0: put the database into administrative use only.  You don't want other updates to be happening while you research the issue.

Comment: Yeah we brought down the environment.