# Undo Deleted Records

Tags: sql-server

My Database has Full BackUp Plan on Every Morning on 01:00 Am. Today I came to work and Deleted all of the Records in a table by mistake in sql server management Studio by running this command

```
delete * from Table1 where 10=10
```

instead of

```
delete * from Table1 where Id=10
```

this happened around  13:00 pm. worktime starts from 8:00 am . is it possible to undo the deleted Records? if I want to recover it from the backup file, I loses the records entered between 8:00 and 13:00. what is the best solution for this problem?

I read this post [Recover deleted records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17803/recover-deleted-records) but it was not the same as mine. and I read it was a duplicate post. but again i couldn't find the the main post for this problem.

Comment: Gah! I assume your transaction log is operating normally? If so, you can do a point in time restore using your transaction log and the full backup. Microsoft has a good write up about it at their site, I assume you are using SQL Server? Use their site if you are: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Oh - this will only work if you are using the Full/Bulk logged recovery mode.

Comment: In the future, always put those sorts of commands within TRANSACTIONS. That way you can roll back the transaction if you have done something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a Major Whoopsie.

Assuming you didn't use transactions around the delete you are stuck with scanning the log files and redoing all the INSERT and UPDATE queries. If you don't have a query log then it's manual entry time.

If it's any consolation the Government of Alaska had a similar issue a while ago, further compounded by the backup tapes not being readable. You've probably lost a morning, they lost the whole thing.

Comment: If transaction is committed and virtual log file which was part of transaction is reused and overwritten even reading log file would not help. Also reading log file using fn_dblog is not recommended practice in Prod env.

Comment: It's also not recommended to run DELETE without a well-considered WHERE clause. His options are limited here, best practices can be summarily tossed out.

Comment: This is not always true if a table has contraint and Identity and you want to remove all records you have to use delete trucate would have after effects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have log backups or differential backups ? I did not find any information about them in your post. Since(I assume)  you do not have transaction log backup point in time recovery is not possible and you cannot recover data changes done after 1 AM. Since your query executed in AUTO COMMIT mode its possible that transaction has committed and changes being made.

From now now on please schedule differential backups if database has simple recovery model and if database has full recovery model schedule trn log backup