# Transaction log records in sql server

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, transaction, recovery, concurrency

Based on **Silberschatz**'s **Database system concepts** book, log file for a transaction has 3 records,

- 1 record for transaction start: `T_i start`,
- 1 for transaction changes on write(x) operation: `T_i,X,V_1,V_2`, where `X` is the data item that has been changed from `V_1`(old value) to `V_2`(new value).
- And 1 for transaction commit(or abort),`T_i commit`.

How can I see these log records in SQL Server? how can I see recovery phase (analyses, redo and undo) in SQL Server?

**Edit:**
The given link in comment, will show me the table log that which executed transaction for example has **delete** command or **update** command. I want to show for example which changes Transaction `T_i` has made to a data item.
For example `T_1,A,100,150` means transaction `T_1` has changed the value of **A** from 100 to 150.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View delete statements in the Transaction log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/view-delete-statements-in-the-transaction-log)

Comment: I think my question is different as I have explained it in **Edit** part.

Comment: From linked article: _you wont find the exact scripts that were executed on sql.(in the transaction log)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Based on Silberschatz's Database system concepts book, log file for a transaction has 3 records

That's the **minimum** you'd need for replay and recovery of individual transactions without any optimizations. There may be *many* more than 3 for a single CRUD item in SQL Server.

> How can I see these log records in SQL Server?

The one I use to see the active log is [sys.fn_dblog](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/) (Link to Remus's log post). Note that this function isn't documented and can/will change and doesn't show things such as Hekaton logs which need to be cracked using sys.fn_dblog_xtp which again isn't documented.

> how can I see recovery phase (analyses, redo and undo) in SQL Server?

Through many hours of painstaking work. You can use sys.fn_dump_dblog() to look at transaction log backups that are taken **after** redo and undo has run.

Since the SQL Server Log records and files aren't documented, except for physical and logical architecture, you'll just have to search the internet and make your own best guesses.

If you're asking because you'd like to make software to deal with the log, then you'll need to get in touch with Microsoft Partner Resources. Otherwise, you're on your own, armed with the collective knowledge of the internet and volumes of your favorite beverage.

> For example T_1,A,100,150 means transaction T_1 has changed the value of A from 100 to 150.

The SQL Server log isn't really human readable, though the functions help. I stated before, it's not always that easy as change 100 to 150.

Let's say you changed 'Hi' to 'Sean'. This might cause a forwarding record, or a page split. It might be the first record in a table, or a heap, or be changed because of multiple indexes.

I'm not trying to put you off, just that academia and the real world and generally two *very* different things.

Comment: There are already some 3rd party tools that do this that OP might be interested in, like [Quest LiteSpeed](https://www.quest.com/documents/litespeed-for-sql-server-datasheet-67891.pdf) and [Apex Log Reader](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx), but you may have vendor reasons for not bringing them up ;)

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Good point! For which I like or have used, no comment ;)