# How do I recover deleted rows from one table while having Recovery SIMPLE Model? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, recovery

How do I recover deleted rows from a table while having Recovery SIMPLE Model? Database is in Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I have managed to find them in `fn_dblog` table before data is overwritten with a new one. Can I do anything with it?

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
```

I also find out the specific time at which rows were deleted.

```
USE Databasename
GO
SELECT
[Current LSN],  Operation, [Transaction ID], [Begin Time], [Transaction Name], [Transaction SID]
FROM
fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
WHERE
[Transaction ID] = ‘000:000001f3'
AND
[Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
```

I've read SIMPLE Recovery doesn’t support transaction log backup. But is there really no way to restore that data?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/995/1186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, you get any recommendation on `fn_dblog` as it's undocumented. So got following options:

1. **Recent Full Backup**: Restore recent full backup as copy without overwriting existing database then you should be able to recover particular table or rows within table.
2. **[Third-party tools](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx)**: you can use third-party tools that can directly read your transaction log to recover data from particular transaction, you need to take database offline to read `.log` file by tool. However, chances are less in this method since the recover model is `SIMPLE` which truncates the log automatically