# What free database software support sequences

Tags: database-design, sequence

I have a requirement that a database must support sequences. I know oracle and PostgreSQL support it. Are there any other free database software that support database sequences? it would be great if it had a .NET driver too

Comment: Why specifically sequences, what are you to use the for? Are you looking for a single integer column which auto-increments? Every database then supports that feature

Comment: @ssmusoke: An auto_increment is something different than a sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If with "free" you mean "open source", then Firebird comes to mind (but I personally would prefer PostgreSQL over it - the much better documentation alone is a reason).

Ingres also supports sequences, but I don't know if there is a .Net driver for it.

There are other open source ones like Apache Derby, HSQLDB and H2 Database but as they are Java only, I'm pretty sure they do *not* have a .Net driver

If with "free" you mean "free of charge", then Oracle Express, DB2 Express-C and SQL Server **2012** Express are an option as well (as all three of them support sequences)

Comment: Actually it would be DB2 Express-C (Express actually has a license cost). But DB2 does support sequences. We use sequences with DB2 Express-C where I work.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich: thanks. I didn't know that there was a difference between Express and Express-C.

Comment: [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1204whicheditiondb2/sidefile-Figure3.html) compares Express vs Express-C as an fyi.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use PostgreSQL then? It's great.

http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html?origref=http://blekko.com/ws/%20oracle%20express%20edition) is free, supports sequences, and can integrate with .NET.  See the question [What features of Oracle make it an attractive choice for small projects?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/what-features-of-oracle-make-it-an-attractive-choice-for-small-projects)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 [introduces sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272694%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).  You can [download SQL Server 2012 Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx) for free, and the .NET integration should go without saying.